# how to verify if multiple IPs written in a line of a text file are valid using shell script?

Tags: bash, shell, ip, sh, ip-address

### I have a text file with content like following :

some random text

some random text

some random text

1000=169.254.1.1 169.254.1.2 169.254.1.3

### 1001=169.254.2.1 169.254.2.2

using a shell script, want to verify if ALL the IPs mentioned against numbers 1000, 1001 are valid IPs.

your help is highly appreciated.

Comment: started learning shell scripting just now, going through the basics and this is a question that I am unable to solve

Comment: What do you mean by valid ? The format or whether they are reachable or not ?

Comment: this is about the format and the range,
e.g. "169.254.1.1" is valid but "1699.254.1.1" is not valid so does "a.b.c.d".

reachability is not a concern at all.

Answer (score 0):

This might do the job. This will check that the IPs have the same format but not the range, for instance an IP as 999.9.9.9 will be taken as valid too, Im trying to figure out a more precise regex but on the mean time, this might help you.

```
count_of_potential_IPs=$( grep -E '100(0|1)=' text.txt | awk -F'=' '{ print $2 }' | tr ' ' '\n' | wc -l)
count_of_valid_IPs=$( grep -E '100(0|1)=' text.txt | awk -F'=' '{ print $2 }' | tr ' ' '\n' | grep -E '[0-9]{1,3}[.][0-9]{1,3}[.][0-9]{1,3}[.][0-9]{1,3}' | wc -l )

if [ $count_of_potential_IPs -eq $count_of_valid_IPs ]
then
    echo "Awesome!, all Ips seem to be valid. The world is regaining its balance! :)"
fi
```

Regards!

Comment: Thanks a ton ! meanwhile I'll try to understand this piece of code.

Comment: this regex seems to be working for me : 

grep -Eo \<((([1-9]|1[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([1-9]|1[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-4]))\>

Comment: Glad to hear you found a good replacement for the original regex. @CodeLearner